# Sage and PayPal shipping details

Tags: paypal, opayo, sage-erp

Does sage allow for the importing of PayPal shipping details once payments via PayPal are made?

So the customer clients physical address to ship the product to - not just simply the email address by which they paid with PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Sage does not belong to PayPal. Not sure the shipping details handling process in Sage. But if you want to keep customers' shipping address, variable 'no_shipping' should be set to '2' when you integrate PayPal Website Payment Standard. While the field 'NOSHIPPING' should be set to '2' if you integrate PayPal Express Checkout.

For the more details about shipping address, see the links below and search the key word 'no_shipping' and 'NOSHIPPING'.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

To acquire the transaction details with shipping address information, PayPal IPN is available for you to use. See the link below for the more details.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/